# How to determine a table name in CodeIgniter Model based on session variable

Tags: codeigniter, model, session-variables

I would like to change a tables name in one of my CodeIgniter models based on a $_SESSION variable. The variable determines the language, and I want to query a different table dependent on the language selected.

Right now I have got this:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');

class Tp_modules_model extends DataMapper {

  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public $table = determineTable($_SESSION['lang']);

  public function getModules($ids) {
    $this->clear();
    return $this->where_in('id', $ids)->get()->all_to_array();
  }

  public function determineTable($lang) {
    if ($lang == 'nl') {
      return 'modules_dutch';
   } else {
      return 'modules';
   }
 }
}
```

but I get this error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in /usr/www/users/staginntkx/application/modules/ecom_bookings/models/tp_modules_model.php on line 9

Is there a workaround for this or another way to change my models tables based on the output of $_SESSION['lang']?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way:

You only declare the variable for table as private/public and then initialize its value in the constructor. Here is how you can do this in your code:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');

class Tp_modules_model extends DataMapper {

private $table;

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    // setting the variable for table as per session variable
    $this->table = determineTable($this->session->userdata('lang');
}

public function getModules($ids) {
  $this->clear();
  return $this->where_in('id', $ids)->get()->all_to_array();
}

public function determineTable($lang) {
  if ($lang == 'nl'){
    return 'modules_dutch';
  }else{
    return 'modules';
  }
}
}
```

you should be using the Codeigniter's session library to set and get the session variable.
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html